# Query to getting the count of users in a specific period of time

Tags: mysql, database

I wanna get count of my users in periods of times in MySQL. I wrote this query (I know that is not correct), but this query only get me count of registered users in periods of times.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(reg_date,  '%Y-%V') AS  'Week', count(*) AS 'Users'
    FROM `users`
    GROUP BY Week
```

Comment: You're looking for a count of users in periods of times, and are only getting a count of registered users in periods of times...you're going to have to be more specific about what you're looking for, because to me it looks like you've already solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by this query:

```
SELECT @week:=DATE_FORMAT(reg_date,  '%X-%V') AS  'week' 
,(SELECT SUM(users)
        FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(reg_date,  '%X-%V') AS  'week', count(*) AS 'users', reg_date
            FROM `users`
            GROUP BY week) AS u
        WHERE week <= @week) AS 'users'
FROM `users`
GROUP BY week
```

### Result:

```
week        users
==================
2013-34     23630
2013-35     24392
2013-36     25801
2013-37     28141
2013-38     29022
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question - as of now - is not very specific, ...

Since you are using a field named reg_date that you group it by, it would suggest that you get the count according to the registeration date, so maybe you need to take a differend Column for your `'Week'`.

Another possibility might be that you need to use a totally different table, where "user actions" (or whatever you are looking for) - instead of the users data - might be stored.